# Scripture on anger from Ephesians

Tags: ephesians

Ephesians 4:26 - I always thought and believed this scripture meant "Before you go to bed at night, shake it off through prayer and supplication or reconciliation with the parties concerned", even the same meaning is conveyed in my native language. But check [this link](http://www.awmi.net/reading/teaching-articles/anger_management/), which nearly means the oppsite
"What happens when the sun goes down? Typically we stop working. The day winds down, and we rest and go to sleep. Paul is saying, Don’t let this godly anger ever stop working. Keep it awake. Stir it up and keep it active"

which is another perspective in looking at the above scripture. Keep your Godly anger without giving the devil a room, may be against any evil?

What exactly the scripture tells us?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! This verse is an interesting one on which already have a Q&A. Please take a look at the answers there.